# How do you count missing data by level of a variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data

I'm looking at the General Social Survey and trying to figure out if there are proportionally more NAs in one level of a variable than in another level. Here's the head of my df.

```
  year PartyBinary agekdbrn
1 1972       Other       NA
2 1972    Democrat       NA
3 1972       Other       NA
```

I haven't seen this answered already here, which seems odd. I've tried several ways, but they all seem to automatically drop or else simply ignore NA data. For example:

```
gss.subset%>%
filter(agekdbrn=="NA")%>%
group_by(year)%>%
summarise(count(agekdbrn))
```

This gives: 
A tibble: 0 × 2
... with 2 variables: year , count(agekdbrn)

Which I found to be incorrect by running the same code with a variable I could see the NAs in. Another try was:

```
gss.subset%>%
group_by(year)%>%
sum(is.na(agekdbrn))
```

Which got me the error message "Error in function_list[k] : object 'agekdbrn' not found", which violates my understanding of the whole purpose of the gss.subset%>% pipe. The following also failed:

```
ggplot(gss.subset, 
aes(x=agekdbrn))+geom_bar(position="fill")+facet_wrap(~year)
```

Gave me a plot without the NAs, something I'm often grateful for, but now annoyed by. Another try was as follows:

```
gss.subset%>%
filter(agekdbrn=="98"|agekdbrn=="99"|agekdbrn=="IAP")%>%
ggplot(aes(x=PartyBinary, fill=agekdbrn))+geom_bar(position="fill")
```

This gives me simply a grey background of a plot, with no geom. Judging by the GSS codebook (http://gss.norc.org/documents/codebook/GSS_Codebook.pdf, CTRL+F "agekdbrn" to see what I'm talking about), I thought that perhaps the NAs were actually coded as 98s, 99s, or "IAPs", but the filter didn't work, as you can see above.

I'm not sure what to do. Clearly there has to be some way to check to see if data are missing randomly or non-randomly, but I'm stumped as to what it would be.

Comment: Try `NA==NA` -- it returns `NA`. Filter to NA with `filter(is.na(agekdbrn))`

Comment: Solutions by both cmaher and B Williams work give output, but they also only get me halfway there: they tell me that there are NAs in the agekdbrn variable, but not the proportions of NAs by PartyBinary. Is there some way I can get the NAs to be represented visually or in a table as a proportion of total responses to agekdbrn by PartyBinary?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add summarise to your 3rd chunk of code

```
gss.subset %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   sum(is.na(agekdbrn))
```

should be

```
gss.subset %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(sum(is.na(agekdbrn)))
```

Comment: `count` or `tally` might also work here (replacing group_by %>% other_function)